# Prevent shell command substitution

Tags: c++, c, shell, command-substitution

Is there  a way to prevent command substitution in a shell script?

For instance, if the script contains a line like:

```
var=`echo foo`
```

I would like a way to get `echo foo`. Not just the substitute of the command which is foo.

**Edit:** I am trying to store these commands for later evalutation. Plus I can't edit the script manually; I need these values in a C/C++ program and that way I would have to somehow parse the script, which kills the purpose (that is exactly what I want to avoid: parsing the script).

**Edit #2:** Full situation explained here: there is this shell script which contains a bunch of variables like this:

```
foo="bar"
baz=`some_command`
```

etc. I want for every variable to store the right part of the expression (i.e. "bar" and `some_command`). I have to do this from within a C/C++ program so I can't manually edit the script (for instance to add single quotes).

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to "secure" a string for `eval`, it's [not quite that simple](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: Are you parsing the script or not? You say you want to get `\`echo foo\`` from `var=\`echo foo\``, which very much looks like shell syntax, not C/C++ syntax. Is the user typing commands in the C/C++ program which should be run in a shell?

Comment: @l0b0: I **don't** want to parse the script (it's a long and painful way). So, I was thinking of spawning a shell as another process and do stuff there with the script. Therefore, yes I'm looking for some shell syntax/magic. I mentioned the C/C++ program to indicate that the script cannot be hand-edited.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your string into single quote.

```
var='`echo foo`'
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I can't hand-edit this script. I want to get these values in a C/C++ program, so I would have to parse the script to find where to put the single quotes, which is exactly the thing I wanted to avoid.